# Generic interface type assignment

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, generic-interface

I would like to have some validators for input for different objects. On of these is User object.
I want to have a generic interface validator for each child class which validates a specific object. The basevalidator is just an abstract class which contains the the abstract method "validate" and some other useful protected methods. But when i try to assign a new UserValidator to a Validator type i get an error. How could i rewrite this?

```
public interface Validator<T> {...}
public abstract class BaseValidator<T> : Validator<T> {...}
public class UserValidator : BaseValidator<User> {...

Validator v = new UserValidator(); //ERROR
```

Comment: Does the interface _have to_ be generic?

Comment: please post the calling site of `v`, or the context in which it will live, because this will be the next construction yard to be opened as soon as you get rid of the compilation error. And please post the entire content of the interface

Answer (score 2):

Actually the error message:

> Using the generic type `'Validator<T>'` requires 1 type arguments

tells you what to do.
You have to specify the generic parameter of the interface:

```
Validator<User> v = new UserValidator(); //NO ERROR
```

Much more important is where you want to use `v`. Because this determines whether `User` is known at compile time or not. Please post more context code, so I can adjust my answer to your actual situation

Comment: If `Validator` interface only contains for example `SomeResult Validate();` then the interface can be completely oblivious of the Type Argument.

Comment: @Fildor I agree, lets see what kind of next information will be flowing in